# $http.post returning error-undefined in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, post

I'm new to angular.  I'm using a controller to grab data from a factory that I've populated with an $http.get that connects to a REST api:

```
videoModule.factory('myFactory', function($http){   
    var factory = {};
    factory.getStuff = function(success, error) {

       return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/backup'});           
    };
    factory.postStuff = function(stuff){

    };
    return factory;
    });
```

Here is my controller code:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http, myFactory){
        myFactory.getStuff().success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            $scope.stuff = data;
            console.log(data);

            $scope.selectedStuff = function($scope, $http){
                var selectedFile = data[0].File_Name;
                var selectedDir = data[0].File_SubDir;

                var pack = selectedDir + "/" + selectedFile;
                console.log(pack);

                var result = { File_Location: pack };
                console.log(result);

                $http.post('api/test', result).success(function(data, status, headers){
                    console.log("Selected Video Sent to /api/test");
            });
            };
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("ERROR", data, status);
        });
    });
```

The first two lines within .success(function()) work fine - they load JS objects that I can use to bind to my HTML.  The next chunk of code works perfectly.  My view has an "ng-click=selectedStuff()" binding.  When that element is clicked, the module logs result, a JS object {File_Location: pack} to my console.

However, I run into trouble in the next three lines.  When I try to POST this object to /api/test, I get an error message in my dev tools:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined at k.$scope.selectedVideo.
```

I'm having trouble figuring out why $http is coming across as undefined.  Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

that's because $`scope.selectedStuff` is expecting two arguments `($scope, $http)` 
and 
in `ng-click=selectedStuff()` you are not sending any parameters leaving $http as undefined in the function.

You can remove the arguments from the function as they can be taken from global scope.

```
$scope.selectedStuff = function(){
            var selectedFile = data[0].File_Name;
            var selectedDir = data[0].File_SubDir;

            var pack = selectedDir + "/" + selectedFile;
            console.log(pack);

            var result = { File_Location: pack };
            console.log(result);

            $http.post('api/test', result).success(function(data, status, headers){
                console.log("Selected Video Sent to /api/test");
        });
        };
```

Also, I would suggest you to consider bringing `$scope.selectedStuff` definition to outside the myFactory.getStuff() success callback.